# Decode Unicode chars in PHP by the unicode number

Tags: php, unicode

I've got characters like

```
&#45;
```

or

```
&#32;
```

The number 45 is the unicode number "#". The "32" is a simple space. But this also have to be possible with numbers like "2123" for some very special special chars.

Now I want to simply decode this characters in PHP. My first try was to use:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode();
```

But this does not work for "#", only for special chars like "ö" or "Ä".

It would be no problem to create a new function for my case (if there is no build-in php-function), but I couldn't find a equivalent function for mssql-server functions like NCHAR() or UNICODE() - which simply return the unicode number of a character and vice versa.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you've found is exactly [what's documented](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode):

> This function is the opposite of [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). It converts
> **special HTML entities** back to characters.
>
> The converted entities are: `&amp;`, `&quot;` (when `ENT_NOQUOTES` is not
> set), `&#039;` (when `ENT_QUOTES` is set), `&lt;` and `&gt;`

You want some other related function, so we scroll down the documentation to the [See Also](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-decode-seealso) section and find [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/html_entity_decode):

> Convert **all HTML entities** to their applicable characters

```
var_dump( htmlspecialchars_decode('&#45;&#32;') );
var_dump( html_entity_decode('&#45;&#32;') );
```

```
string(10) "&#45;&#32;"
string(2) "- "
```